# How to use Jquery third party plugin with Angular 7?

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular7

I have added  jquery and a jquery third party plugin "**stiffChart**" with my Angular 7 project. I have install jquery and the plugin in my project. Declare the same in angular.json file but while calling the plugin method I am getting the following error.

Error: [ts] Property 'stiffChart' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import * as $ from'jquery';
interface JQuery {   stiffChart(options?: any): any; }
@Component({   
    selector: 'app-demo',   templateUrl:   './demo.component.html',   
    styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css'] })
    export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
     $('#your-chart-name').stiffChart({});
 }}
```

Please let me know what is wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Please mention the point against the negative vote..

Comment: Hi Did you solve this issue ? I´ve been facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to include script of jquery and plug-in  in the angular.json file.